# Developer perspective Hive upgrade 0.12 vs 0.13

Tags: hive

I build a usecase/project with Hive 0.12 using normal simple hive queries(joins, multi insert and partitions). Now, i'm planning to upgrade to Hive 0.13. From the developer perspective will there be any impact on my usecase after upgrade.

I mean any code changes are need to make my project running fine with Hive 0.13!!

Please suggest
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Default handling of data type *DECIMAL* has changed a lot from 0.12 to 0.13

`cast('123' as decimal) /10` will return **12.3** with V0.12 (handled as an Oracle NUMBER(38) i.e. floating point) but **12** with V0.13+ (handled as an Oracle NUMBER(38,0) i.e. big integer)

That's all I'm aware of.